# Cloudera Hadoop - install error

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I'm new to Linux and Hadoop. I want to learn the basics of Pig, MapReduce and Hive and I'm trying to install Cloudera's Hadoop solution on Ubuntu.
[This](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_path_A.html?scroll=cmig_topic_6_5) is the tutorial I'm following.
I'm stuck on Step 1. I'm not using a proxy, so I skipped the proxy configuration steps. Got to step 1.6, and then I get the following error message. Any ideas what I should try?

```
Refreshing repository metadata failed. See /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer/2.refresh-repo.log for details. Click OK to revert this installation.
```

And this is what's on that log file:

```
Hit http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4 Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4 Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4/contrib Sources
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release
Hit http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4/contrib TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4/contrib Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com precise-cm4/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have broken repository references that are unrelated to Cloudera, but causing your install to fail.

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
...
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa.  Specifically look for `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto`.